# windows 2008 R2 DFSdiag error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

When I run the command

dfsdiag /testdfsintegrity /dfsroot:\domain\dfs full

I get the following error

Checking the registry of the namespace servers...
Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
Warning: Unable to verify the registry of the following namespace server: DC1

I have been trying to look what this does but can find anything on it.

Comment: Are you running this command with an account that has permission to access the registry on DC1?  Does DC1 have a firewall that is blocking the command from running?

Comment: I am running the command as domain admin, I have also  tried running the command on DC1 and I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KEY was missing in registry

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DFS\Roots

was Present in DC2 and DC3

Comment: Thanks for the lead.  In my case, one of the servers was missing a value in one of the subkeys: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DFS\Roots\domainv2`.

Comment: We were getting clients picking up the wrong DFSN namespace root target, and dfsutil /PktInfo was returning AccessStatus: 0xc000003a. The failing DFS Namespace servers were all missing subkeys and values under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DFS\Roots\domainv2\<rootname>` - now working fine.